# How to sort users by number of followers in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

This is pretty self-explanatory, but here is some more info:

I am using mongoose with node, and have schemas set up as follows:

```
User
  name
  password

Follow
  user
  following
```

Is there any clean way of doing this, without having a follower count field in each user doc and have to modify two documents for every follow?

Comment: What is "following"? An ObjectID? A username? An array of one of those?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume following is a single value object id pointing to a user. I'm going to assume you have the user_id already, in a variable `user_id`.

In regular shell javascript:

```
db.follow.find({following:user_id}).count();
```

In mongoose:

```
Follow.count({following:user_id}, callback);
```

**update** Sorry, I somehow missed the title of the post and thought you were just looking to do counts. You probably will end up needing to store the counts to do sorting on the fly. There are some features in the JIRA up for votes that might make this easier in the future, though.